# Django url (slug)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

The question is, I have a mini-blog, there are articles and user profile (pages).
I display articles at site/**articlename**
I want to display the user account at site/**username**

**views.py** (article):

```
def post_detail(request, slug):  
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', {'post': post })
```

**views.py** (profile users):

```
class UserProfileView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'users/profile/profile-user-view.html'
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        username = self.kwargs.get("username")
        return get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
```

URL's:

```
path('<str:username>', UserProfileView.as_view(), name='user_detail')
path('<slug:slug>', views.post_detail, name='post_detail')
```

Now my user profile opens at site/**username**, but the article does not open at
site/**article name**.

I suspect some kind of conflict in the URL (slug). How can I make it so that both articles and an account at the site / address are opened without additional directories. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use one path and afterwards check in the view if the given string exists as username or article in your database and then do the appropriate action.

```
path('<str:path_string>', YourView.as_view(), name='yourview')
```

Then in the view just do 2 queries on users and posts with the path_string as filter. If one of the querysets is not empty you got a match and you can render the appropriate template.
Something like

```
post=Post.objects.filter(title=path_string)
user=User.objects.filter(username=path_string)
If post:
....
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't know how to express this in syntax

Comment: I updated my answer .. does this help you?

Comment: tjanks, could you write the complete views.py? I seem confused(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@Razenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13510123/razenstein), I think I got it:

```
def two_href(request, path_string):
    
        username = User.objects.filter(username=path_string)
        slug = Post.objects.filter(slug=path_string)
    
        if username:
            ...       
        elif slug:   
            ... 
        else:
            raise Http404("404 error")
```

url:

```
path('<str:path_string>', views.two_href, name='two_href')
```